# ssh connection closed by remote after 1m when i use ipv6 host name

Tags: linux, macos, ubuntu, ssh, ipv6

I'm trying to ssh login in my desktop pc from my macbook over ipv6. For convenience, I name the ipv6 address in `/etc/hosts`, But each time I connected to it over the hostname, it will be automatic closed after 1 minute if I don't do anything! However, no prombles will occur if I use the ipv6 address directly!

When I run the command `ssh -vvv myname@hostname`, after 1 minute I do nothing, it will output this:

```
debug3: send packet: type 1
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug3: channel 0: status: The following connections are open:
  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i0/0 o0/0 e[write]/0 fd 6/7/8 sock -1 cc -1)

debug3: fd 1 is not O_NONBLOCK
Connection to ubuntu closed by remote host.
Connection to ubuntu closed.
Transferred: sent 3552, received 3940 bytes, in 60.2 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 59.0, received 65.4
debug1: Exit status -1
```

operating system of my computer:

- macbook: macOS Big Sur 11.6
- desktop computer: ubuntu 20.04

What's the reason that may cause this problem? How can I solve it?

Your help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are bugs in ssh provided by MacOS.
I run the follow command to install the openssh, and restart the terminal, the problem solved.

```
brew install openssh
```